# Has the 'Peter Principle' ever been proven or disproven?

Tags: psychology, management

According to Wikipedia, the [Peter Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peter_Principle) states that "in a hierarchy every employee tends to rise to his level of incompetence". Aside from anecdotal evidence, has this ever been proven or disproven by science?

Comment: I wonder how this could be researched. How do you measure incompetence of "every employee in a hierarchy"? You can take some success and failure rates of people, but testing this in general isn't easy.

Comment: Corollary? A company that never promotes anyone outperforms a company that offers promotions.

Comment: It is self evidently true of meritocracies, don't you think?

Comment: I'm thinking the same as Martin...How do you quantify?  Everyone that's ever worked in nearly any environment has seen this... The notion that just because you were a dynamite salesman would make you a competent manager does not often hold water.

Comment: I know of some companies that have policies designed to limit the damage done by the Peter Principle, and have some anecdotes of people who benefited from the policies; either getting put back to the job they excelled at without loss of benefits or being allowed some time to adapt and learn until they *were* ready for their new position. But I agree with the other commentators, this would be hard to measure.

Answer (score 7):

In this discussion paper,

- Lazear, Edward P., [The Peter Principle: A Theory of Decline (April 2003)]. IZA Discussion Paper No. 759. Available at SSRN

the author argues that the effects of the Peter Principle can be explained by a regression-to-the-mean rather than poor promotion practices.

More importantly, for this question, he summarises some of the evidence (with references):

> There is substantial evidence of the Peter Principle. In addition to papers from the
>   marketing and organizational behavior literature, there are a number of findings in empirical labor
>   economics that support the claim. In an early paper that used subjective performance evaluation,
>   Abraham and Medoff (1980) reported that workers’ subjective evaluation scores fell, the longer they
>   were on the job. In Lazear (1992), it was found that the coefficient of job tenure in a wage
>   regression was actually negative. The longer a worker was in a particular job, given his tenure in
>   the firm, the lower his wage. The reason presumably is that the better workers are promoted out of
>   the job so those with a given number of years of firm experience who have fewer years in a job are
>   less likely to have gotten stuck in that job. Baker, Gibbs and Holmstrom (1994) replicate this
>   finding in their data and Gibbs and Hendricks (2001) find that raises and bonuses fall with tenure.

So, **yes, there is empirical evidence that the Peter Principle holds**, even if there is controversy about *why* it holds.